# Restricted FolderBrowserDialog, recommended solution

Tags: .net, winforms, customization, folderbrowserdialog

We want to prevent the user from doing **anything** except selecting a folder. We don't want to allow him to delete files/folders, rename them, access the context menu, etc. But we can't override anything since FolderBrowserDialog is sealed.

We googled around and found some solutions:

- Implement our own FolderBrowserDialog: Don't have time for this, only acceptable as last resort
- [This guy](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dialog/OpenFileDialogEx.aspx) did it for an OpenFileDialog, might work but seems a little overkill

Anyone faced this problem and found an optimal solution for this? It must be .NET 4.0 compatible

Comment: That's an odd restriction. Why do you want to do that? If the user has the rights, he can do it from the explorer anyway.

Comment: What's the point of restricting this?  The user will simply switch to another program, like Explorer.  Enforce user access rights with a normal Windows security policy, anything else is a security hole.

Comment: Maybe it's a kiosk type of environment where explorer can't be accessed.

Comment: It's just like Charles said, the user can't access Windows or Explorer. It's part of the requirements, I don't have a say on that. I got it working except for this detail; actually, I'm using the deprecated VB6 DriveDirListBox control and I want to replace it to get rid of the compilation warnings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, we solved it implementing our own control. It was a lot simpler than we thought. In short, we just made a class inherit from System.Windows.Forms.Form, with a System.Windows.Forms.TreeView on the left and a System.Windows.Forms.ImageList on the right to show the current folder's contents. Then we DllImport'ed SHGetFileInfo and ExtractIconEx from Shell32 in order to make the TreeView and ImageList's icons look like Explorer's, and voila!

Answer (score 1):

You best bet is to use a control like [FolderView](http://www.ssware.com/fldrview.htm) from Shell MegaPack - it is customizable in the way you want it - you can turn of shell context menus, renaming, drag-drop, keyboard shortcuts, etc,

DISCLAIMER: We are the developers of FolderView mentioned above.

Comment: Sorry, we need a free solution