# select and display full path in a text box

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am trying to use the browse dialog to allow the user to select a folder then display the full path of the folder in a text box. I am also trying to check if the the user types the path into the text box then check to see if the folder exists if not create it and put the full path in the text box. Here is what I have so far.

```
Dim directory As System.IO.DirectoryInfo
Dim fullPath As String

fullPath = FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath
If (Not System.IO.Directory.Exists(fullPath)) Then
    'get full path
    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(fullPath)
    'diplay full path in text box
    directoryPath.Text = fullPath.GetFullPath(fullPath)
Else
    'diplay full path in text box
    directoryPath.Text = fullPath.GetFullPath(fullPath)
End If
```

Comment: @Vache I am trying to open a dialong and select a folder then return the folder path to the text box

Comment: Well I see that, but it looks like you already have some code going. What problems do you have?

Comment: @Vache it says GetFullPath is not a member of string

Comment: It's actually a member of System.IO.Path => http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfullpath(v=vs.110).aspx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have

```
folderBrowserDialog1.ShowNewFolderButton = True
```

FolderBrowser control creates the folder when the user pushes the button and does not require you to manually create it in your code. It returns control to your application when it has finished creating the folder. If the user decides to just select a folder, the selected folder name is returned in the same property as the created folder name. Example:

```
Dim result As DialogResult = Me.FolderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog()
If result = DialogResult.OK Then
    directoryPath.Text = Me.FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath
Else
    directoryPath.Text = String.Empty
End If
```

However, I would like to suggest that this control is dangerous because the user may mess things up. See: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6588229/restricted-folderbrowserdialog-recommended-solution).

Answer (score 0):

How should a user select a directory which is not available? You might set `ShowNewFolderButton` to `true`.

C#:

```
using (var dialog = new FolderBrowserDialog())
{
    dialog.ShowNewFolderButton = true;

    if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        directoryPath.Text = dialog.SelectedPath;
    }
}
```

Nevertheless `SelectedPath` should be the absolute path.